# YouTube API retrieving data slows my site down significantly when loading

Tags: php, api, youtube

I am using YouTube's api to load current data of videos that users share on the site in a feed like Facebook, the thing is that it slows my website down a great amount, it's about 2-4 seconds per set of data, so if I have one video 2-4 seconds, then 2 videos 4-8 seconds, etc. So my question is is there a way to not retrieve ALL of the data with this, and speed it up more. (I store the title and description of the video in my own database when the user shares it, but other data I can't. Here's my code:

```
 $JSON = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={$videoID}&alt=json");
 $JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
 $ratings = $JSON_Data->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'gd$rating'}->{'average'};
 $totalRatings = number_format($JSON_Data->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'gd$rating'}->{'numRaters'});
 $views = number_format($JSON_Data->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'});
```

I also load the thumbnail in, which I may go back to saving the thumbnail on my server on submission, but it doesn't seem to be what is slowing it down so much, because when I remove it it still takes a long time.

```
 $thumbnail = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$videoID."/2.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CURL, file_get_contents ..... its not the point.

The big point is : CACHE THE RESPONSE !

Use memcached, file system, data base or whatever but never call API on page load

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is generally something PHP is not very good at doing.

It simply doesn't support multithreading and threads is exactly what you want to do (perform all the  http requests simultaneously, so that their latency is merged).

Perhaps you can move this part of the logic into the browser, by using javascript? The XMLHTTPRequest object in JavaScript supports multithreading.

As far as I know, the only way to do it in PHP is to use raw sockets (`fsockopen(); fwrite(); fread(); fclose();`), but that isn't for the feint of heart... you'll need to be familiar with the HTTP specification.

And finally, does the content change much? Perhaps you can have a local cache of the html in a database, and a cron job (that might run every 30 seconds) to rebuild the cache? This might be a violation of google's terms of service.

Really the best solution would be to do the server communication with some other language, one that supports threading, and talk to that with your PHP script. I'd probably use Ruby.

Comment: Yeah getting into the raw sockets isn't something I would really even bother doing as the information isn't entirely that important, but just something I want to have just because I can, or maybe I can't if I want my site to be fast as it needs to be. All I'm doing with the data is just" 377,532,329 Views
4.9 out of 5 (1,323,742 Ratings)"

I had tried loading these parts of the data in with an ajax call on each post that had a video, but it didn't seem to have any effect, though I may be able to do it another way, just a bit more coding for that.